# show my twitter page timeline on android app

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am trying to show my twitter page timeline in my social app so I did a lot of researches about that and I find twitter kit for android [this](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Getting-Started) 
but it didn't work because they stop supporting it and will delete it from GitHub
in October then I searched again and found fabric so I tried to use it but I found that Google's acquisition of Fabric from Twitter, Twitter Kit is no longer available via Fabric so it, so it can't be done throw fabric so, is there any other way to do it ?